# Using anonymous records gives syntax error: FS0010: Unexpected symbol '|' in expression

Tags: f#

I'm eager to use F# 4.6 anonymous records, but the compiler doesn't seem to "get it". How can I specify that I'm using 4.6? I've tried a lot of googling, but there's no documentation on how to actually tell the compiler to use the newest version(?).

Starting a new `dotnet new console -lang F# -o src/App`, and trying to make a dummy example:

```
open System

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let myrec = {| X=3; Y=4 |}
    printfn "Hello World from F#! test %A" myrec
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

Doesn't work because:

```
src/App/Program.fs(5,18): error FS0010: Unexpected symbol '|' in expression [src/App/App.fsproj]
src/App/Program.fs(5,17): error FS0604: Unmatched '{' [src/App/App.fsproj]
```

my App.fsproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Program.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Do you have VS 2019 or .NET Core >= 2.1?

Comment: I don't use Visual Studio, and don't want to depend on an IDE for the code to run, so I use `dotnet` (the cli tool). I've installed the newest version of both dotnet and the .net core. (At least, the newest where mac is supported). Could it be a mac thing? Do  I need to restart the computer after the install? (which would be weird, but: in desperate times.....)

Comment: Can you confirm `dotnet --version` returns some version > `2.1`? (e.g. for me it is `2.2.202` and your code works... but then I'm on Windows ¯\_(ツ)_/¯).

Comment: dotnet version is 2.2.107.  But it was the runtime that was outdated, not the SDK. I was hasitant to install the very latest version on this page: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2 because it said it said it had issues on MacOS (my OS). But I just went ahead and installed it anyway, and now it finally works =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it *was* my *.NET Core Runtime* that was too far behind. I didn't install the very most recent version because of the unstability warning for MacOS, but I now see that you need the MacOS-unstable version for it to support F# 4.6.

The solution was to just go to https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2 and install the most recent version anyway!

Comment: Just a nit to this: it’s “VS for Mac unstable”; the latest SDK is perfectly fine for macOS provided you’re not using VS for Mac.